# How to sync all git actions between two environments

Tags: git

I am setting up my local environment. Currently our workflow (in theory) looks something like this:

```
+--------------+
|   ssh TEST   |
+--------------+
      X
      X    (All git actions via ssh)
      X
 +------------+
 |    TEST    |
 +-----+------+
 ^     |
 |     | (automatic ftp sync)
 |     v
 +-----+------+
 |     LOCAL  |
 +------------+
```

I was wondering if syncing the `.git` folders on two machines will sync all things git. Is there a better way of dealing with a scenario like this?